# Can't Access IPv6 Address on VM from Internet

Tags: windows, routing, virtual-machines, ipv6

I'm not very familiar with VM staff (and Windows) but am having the following issue.

Host: CentOS 8
Guest: Windows 10
VM: KVM-QEMU
and
Host: Windows Server 2019 Standard
Guest: Windows 10
VM: Hyper-V

In both cases, I can ping6 to the guest Windows 10 from all my devices in our LAN including an IPv6 gateway but cannot from the Internet. Both host servers are accessible from the Internet through IPv6. traceroute6 reaches our gateway but doesn't proceed to the guests. The following is the sample IPv6 assignments:

CentOS host:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.111  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::d6a2:25e4:256:711  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2001:XXX:YYY::1000:1  prefixlen 48  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether 0c:c4:XX:XX:2a:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 737819  bytes 3070877722 (2.8 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 46045  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 336852  bytes 29787637 (28.4 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:feea:ea1b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x2
    ether fe:54:00:XX:XX:1b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 19344  bytes 8897740 (8.4 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 300884  bytes 39466247 (37.6 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions
```

Windows 10 on KVM-QEMU is assigned to 2001:XXX:YYY::1000:2/48 using the above br0 (bridge).

Does anybody have an idea why this happens?
Both guest Windows can access any IPv6 hosts in the Internet and are on the gateway's NDP table.
Thank you.

Comment: Why is your prefix set to 48? How are you getting network connectivity to your VMs?

Comment: Because our ISP gave us /48 addresses. On CentOS, I use bridge as describe at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-kvm-on-centos-8-headless-server/

Comment: You're supposed to subnet that!

Comment: You mean like 2001:XXX:YYY::1000:2/128 for guest?

Comment: IPv6 subnets are /64.

Comment: All right, I'll try that but why are other servers OK with /48?

Comment: What is your actual network?

Comment: Well, I cannot show you but our ISP is Comcast and we use Ethernet Dedicated Internet.

Comment: But you only have one LAN segment?

Comment: /48 v6 subnets are perfectly acceptable to use, so long as all services are on the same segment. However, once you do setup the /48 on a segment, you will need to re-do your IP addressing in order to break up the /48. And @MichaelHampton saying that "IPv6 subnets are /64" is the equivalent to "IPv4 subnets are /24" which is incorrect. A subnet is anything from a /0 (the entire IPv4 space from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255) all the way to a /32 (a single IP address).

Comment: @ChristopherH Um, no, that is not equivalent to saying an IPv4 subnet is /24. This is a much more complex issue than can be discussed in a comment; you need to go read RFC 7421 (and possibly other documents).

Comment: I got an official message from Comcast that /48 can be used as a segment without subnetting /64.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could figure this out after all..

Enabling VM guest Windows 10's "Inbound Rules - Virtual Machine Monitoring (Echo Request - ICMPv6-In)" firewall rule solved this problem. This worked at least with Windows Server but I haven't checked with CentOS yet.